# sql add year statement

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g

I have `sysdate` in one column and I want to add two years in another. I would not like to use `sysdate + 365`

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

select add_months(sysdate, 12) from dual

Comment: Shouln't it be add_months(sysdate, 24) instead?

Comment: Oh yes, that's right.  I saw sysdate + 365 and thought one year but you did say two years.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT your_date_column + interval '2' year
FROM dual
```